# How do I emulate the Google apps modal?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-material

On all of Google's apps, they have the little `apps` button (https://storage.googleapis.com/material-icons/external-assets/v4/icons/svg/ic_apps_black_24px.svg) that opens a modal like so:

[image: Image of modal]

How would I emulate this modal type (both the modal and the labelled icons)? I'm using VueJS and [Vue Material](http://vuematerial.github.io/) but I've got a strong feeling this is outside of the scope of either.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use flexbox to create a table-like layout, with rows and columns of `<span>`s with the image, and then a centered `<p>` under it.

Comment: Could you give me an example? I've been messing around with flexbox but it's been annoying in not cooperating.

Comment: @AniSkywalker I personally don't have much experience in Flexbox, but it looks like you could use something like http://flexboxgrid.com/.